# Delphi fmx how to click through image and form?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I make a transparent form with TImage and can't click mouse through image.
Through transparent form I can click without problems, but no idea how to click through image.

Comment: image OnClick not working ?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with TImage component. Athleast not without making heavy changes to it.

Comment: You can click through a TImage if you set HitTest property on the TImage to false.

Comment: to expand @DougRudd comment, if HitTest to False doesn't work, also set the Locked property to True.

Comment: this is first what I tried... not helping

Comment: What do you mean you have a "Transparent Form"? You mean you have a transparent form on top of another form? If so, use a layout or rectangle instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

On an OnClick Event you could **temporarily hide the Form/Image**, then **simulate a Mouseclick** Event and then **show the Form/Image**.

*This is definitive **not the best solution**, but it may work anyway.*

Answer (score -1):

sorry, I forget to say that I need click not only through image but through image and form (I change topic name now)
so this is answer correct for me:
SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);

Comment: Hi Wataru, if [ワタルシロ](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5933591/%e3%83%af%e3%82%bf%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b7%e3%83%ad) s answer solves your question, you should accept his answer.